# htmlagilitypack won't parse a table

Tags: c#, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a simple data table from the following link:

http://www.tase.co.il/TASE/General/Company/companyHistoryData.htm?subDataType=0&companyID=001390&shareID=01100957

You will get the table, clicking the light green submit image on the lower left. The table id is: `HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1`
Trying to parse it using htmlagilitypack - using the following code:

```
HtmlNode dataTable = document.GetElementbyId("HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1");

HtmlNodeCollection dataTableRow = dataTable.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr");
```

I get a very dirty `html`, with 351 `<TR>` tags, but the content is not even close to the table content...

Comment: The link's html doesn't seem to contain any table with id 'HistoryData1_gridHistoryData_DataGrid1'. Also, //tbody means you start at the root, not at the current node.

Comment: You probably want `./tbody/tr`

Comment: Great - solved by the '//' thing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 datatable.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr");
```

use:

```
 datatable.SelectNodes("./tbody/tr");
```